# list to dataframe with known columns

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe

I have a below list.

```
[['Name', 'Mike', 'score', '15', 'day','12'], 
['Name', 'Dan', 'score', '65'],  
['Name', 'John', 'score', '88', 'day','12'], 
['Name', 'Jack', 'day','12']]
```

I would like to get dataframe as output with all missing data as na. Can you help?

```
Name | Score | Day
Mike | 15    | 12
Dan  | 65    | na
John | 88    | 12
Jack | na    | 12
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create dictionary with zip pair and unpairs values of nested lists to list of dictionaries and pass to `DataFrame` constructor:

```
L = [['Name', 'Mike', 'score', '15', 'day','12'], 
['Name', 'Dan', 'score', '65'],  
['Name', 'John', 'score', '88', 'day','12'], 
['Name', 'Jack', 'day','12']]

df = pd.DataFrame([dict(zip(x[::2], x[1::2])) for x in L])
print (df)
   Name score  day
0  Mike    15   12
1   Dan    65  NaN
2  John    88   12
3  Jack   NaN   12
```

Thank you @Jon Clements for improvement:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(zip(x[::2], x[1::2])) for x in L)
print (df)
   Name score  day
0  Mike    15   12
1   Dan    65  NaN
2  John    88   12
3  Jack   NaN   12
```

Comment: No real need to build a list of `dict`s here - just `pd.DataFrame(dict(zip(el[::2], el[1::2])) for el in data)` will suffice

Answer (score 0):

You can convert this to a list of dictionaries with:

```
DataFrame([dict(zip(i, i)) for i in map(iter, data)])
```

For the given sample data, this yields:

```
>>> pd.DataFrame([dict(zip(i, i)) for i in map(iter, data)])
   Name  day score
0  Mike   12    15
1   Dan  NaN    65
2  John   12    88
3  Jack   12   NaN
```